# Searching two different strings in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

Last question on this subject - I promise!! I've been trying a variety of commands.

I need to find files in a directory that have a string "bcs" in it and also end in numbers going from 161-190.

For example:

```
ls
albcs182
albcs188
```

I can get all the files with bcs string using the find command but I'm having trouble searching for two strings in one command?

Comment: Totally unmaintainable `find \( -name '*bcs*1[6-8][0-9]' -o -name '*bcs*190' \) -not -name '*bcs*160'`

Comment: A better place to ask this question is on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Too much scary `ls | foo` in this thread, I give up on this one :/ http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work with all filenames :

```
find -print0 | perl -ne 'INIT { $/ = "\0" } chomp;
  print "$_\n" if /bcs.*?(\d+)$/g && ($1>160 && $1<=190);'
```

Comment: I had edited your post with the only good response and voted +1. I added missing `bcs` string in the match too. Hope you agree. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @sputnick: yes, I agree :) and shame on me for forgetting the `bcs` string

Answer (score 0):

```
ls | egrep ".*bcs.*(16[1-9]|1[7-8][0-9]|190)$"
```